# Could I use an entire Hibernate entity for searching from db based on the fields which are populated?

Tags: hibernate, search, entity

In my application, there is a search screen for each entity from which the user could fill one or more fields which would act as filters for retrieving the list of objects. I need to find an easy method by which to query the database based on whatever fields the user decides to populate which may not be the primary key. So the entity which I receive would have random properties populated and if I need to create HQL from that, I would have to painstakingly append conditions for each of the non-null fields, and there are tables which contain a lot of fields. So I need to search by the entire entity and not just the primary key. Please help me in this regard. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

What you describe is called "Query By Example", it's a common requirement so there is specific support to automate it.

Now that you know how it's called, you should be able to find plenty of examples for it.